# finding substring

Tags: python

Thanks in advance.
    I have a string:

```
A = 'asdfghjklmn'
```

How can I get a substring having a maximum length which is a multiple of three?

Comment: You must elaborate what "multiple of three" means. Some examples would be useful.

Comment: the question is rather vague. Are you looking for a substring that's as long as possible while satisfying the restraint or simply any substring which is a multiple of 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation) and integer arithmetic.

```py
>>> a = 'asdfghjklmn'
>>> a[:len(a)//3*3]
'asdfghjkl'   
>>> len(a)
11
>>> len(a[:len(a)//3*3])
9
```

In general, `n//k*k` will yield the largest multiple of *k* less than or equal to *n*.

Comment: Thank you.useful for gene sequence analysis

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're looking for something like this:

```
>>> A = 'asdfghjklmn'
>>> mult, _ = divmod(len(A), 3)
>>> A[:mult*3]
'asdfghjkl'
```

here resulting string will have length which is multiple of three and it will be the longest possible substring of `A` with such length.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another example:

```
>>> A = '12345678'
>>> A[:len(A) - len(A)%3]
'123456'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
A = 'asdfghjklmn'
A[0:(len(A)/3)*3]
'asdfghjkl'
```

Comment: does not run on python3: Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an index method. You should have used floor division (just as Stephan202 did). See http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238

Answer (score 0):

With the foreword that it will never be as efficient as the ones that actually use *math* to find the longest multiple-of-3-substring, here's a way to do it using regular expressions:

```
>>> re.findall("^(?:.{3})*", "asdfghjklmn")[0]
'asdfghjkl'
```

Changing the `3` quantifier will allow you to get different multiples.